# Document Properties override Item title

Tags: 2010

Situation:

I upload a Word file. The Word file does not have the document       property "Title" filled in.
The SharePoint item title column is empty because of this.
I fill the column with a title e.g "MyDocument".
Later I update the item and the title column is empty because SharePoint takes the empty title of the document.

How can I prevent/fix this behavior? maybe a event-receiver which save the old title and writes this title after the update back?

Greetings,
AHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the document from SharePoint rather than uploading a new copy, which is in effect telling it to overwrite the metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a workflow to update the title when a document is created. Have a look at the answers [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/lookup-column-to-documents-library/59263#59263)

Answer (score 0):

We've experienced this issue with XLSX files. You could use doc/xls files, which don't seem to have this issue.