# Lookup column to Picture Library

Tags: 2013, list, custom-list, lookup-column, picture-library

I've created a picture library called "Reusable icons" with all my icons.
Then I created a new Custom List with a lookup column to the "Reusable icons"-library.

Problem is that I don't get the url or image name in the lookup column. In the picture library I have one column called "name" that shows the image name.

[image]

How can I get the lookup column to choose from the name? I don't see the name column in the dropdown list

[image]

I can't use Title, because that can be different to the actual filename! Doesn't picture library have a easy way to get the url to the image? Seems strange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the way SharePoint works, it only lets you add some specific columns(can't really remember which ones at the moment) as look-up columns, I had same issue few years ago, only solution I could find it that add a item adding event receiver and change Title column to file's name.

There is no other way around I ever came across.

Similar post:

[Lookup column to Documents library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25013/lookup-column-to-documents-library)

Comment: What about calculated column?

Comment: I never tried it myself, but I still don't believe it would work, AFAIR SharePoint uses joins for look-up columns and it all happens at database level - again, I did this research an year ago or so..